# Correct proof of divisibility question?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

After having a disagreement with my teacher I posted the following question a few days ago and I have now rewritten my proof with all the comments I received earlier in mind. Would anyone like to comment if anything is still missing or if it looks good?

Q: Let a and b be integers such that gcd(a,b)=1 and let c be a third integer. Show that if a|bc then a|c.

(Note: I am aware that there are other and better proofs such as from Bezouts identity, but still like to know if the one I came up with was valid)

Proof: Any integer that divides another integer is also a factor of that integer. Since a|bc, a is a factor of bc and all the factors of a are factors of bc. Therefore, one and only one of three options holds true for factors >1; either some of the factors of a are factors of b and some of c, or all of the factors of a are factors of b and none of c, or similarly all of the factors of a are factors of c and none of b. In the trivial case that a=1, a|c because 1 divides any integer, and if b=1 then bc=c and we know that a|bc. Considering that gcd(a,b)=1, a and b have no common factors (except number 1), so the first option above can not be true. For the same reason, neither can the second option be valid. We can now conclude that the third option must be the correct one; all of the factors of a are factors of c and none of b (except number 1). This means that because a is itself one of the factors of a, a must be a factor to c, and so a|c.

Short version:
all factors of a are factors of bc (a|bc)
a and b have no common factors except number 1 (gcd(a,b)=1)
all factors of a must then be factors to c and therefore a|c

Comment: Doesn't look good.  $6$ divides $3\times 4$ yet $6$ is a factor of itself and $6$ divides neither $3$ nor $4$.  So your initial decomposition into cases is not valid in general.

Comment: I read "edited" in the title, but cannot see any edit.

Comment: Worth noting:  the claim in question is highly non-trivial, even when $a$ is a prime. Usually it is proved using Bezout's Identity or the equivalent.

Comment: You might like reading about the [Hilbert numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_number).  Very simple notion, yet it shows how subtle the concept of unique factorization is.

Comment: In that case some of the factors of a are factors of b (factor 3) and some of c (factor 2) I dont see how it shows my cases are not valid? I am stating that a and b have no common factors  as the reason why the case you bring up is not an option in this specific case. If b=3 and a=6 then they do have common factors.

Comment: I know that one proof is from au+bv=1, but I Amsterdam curious if the idea I camembert upp with on an exam was actually valid.

Comment: I am*.. Came up with*

Comment: @Celtschk I have made a new post instead of editing the old one because I changed so much

Comment: I think you are implicitly assuming what you are trying to prove. Try to apply your proof to some domain where unique factorization breaks down, and you may see what goes wrong. For example, in ${\bf Z}[\sqrt6]$, $2$ is relatively prime to both $4+\sqrt6$ and $4-\sqrt6$ but divides their product. In ${\bf R}[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz)$, $x$ is relatively prime to both $y$ and $z$, but divides their product.

Comment: You claim on and only 1 of three options are possible: 1) some factors are factors of b and some of c (and some factors aren't factors of either). 2) all factors are factors of b, and 3) all factors are factors of c.  Why is this true.  Why not none are factors of b and some but not all are factors of c?

Comment: I think most of the comments (but not me) here are assuming that you have not proven the fundsmental theorem of arithmetic (that all integers have a unique prime factorization) and that this question is a *step* on the way to that.  If you haven't proven the FTA then you can not do your options.  If you have, then you can but I think it'd be easier and clearer to talk of prime factors.

Comment: @fleablood to answers your first comment, the reason is because as stated "all factors of a are factors of bc". So if only some are of c and none of b then how could all factors of a be of bc?

Comment: @Gerry I will need some time to think through what youre saying, I am a first year student so some of it is pretty new to me. Please check back to see my response :)

Comment: @Fleablood I didnt realize I might have to prove FTA first and not just assume it. You say it could be done with prime numbers instead, how would that kind of proof look campared to mine above?

Comment: Your cases do not allow for some of the factors of $a$ to be factors of neither of $b,c$.  You say that is covered by option $1$, but in that case you can't claim that $\gcd (a,b)=1$ implies that option $1$ is eliminated, as it is still possible that factors of $a$ are factors of neither $b$ nor $c$.

Comment: Note:  I certainly assume that unique factorization is not acceptable as a tool for proving this (you really need this, or something like it, to prove unique factorization).

Comment: @lulu Im not sure if I stated it clear enough but by beginning with saying "all factors of a are factors of bc"  I mean to exclude the option you give that "it is possible that factors of a  are factors of neither b or c". If some factors of a are factors of neither b or c how could they be factors of bc? So the options where supposed to be stated in the context of the premiss mentioned above, but maybe I didnt get it right.

Comment: Try to describe the cases clearly and in detail; I think you'll hit a problem.  Read the article on Hilbert Numbers I linked to earlier.  That describes a simple situation in which most of the rules of arithmetic still hold, but unique factorization fails (more to the point, the claim you are trying to prove fails).

Comment: @Lukas Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is a right if you want to explain it to someone but as an exam answer it would be lengthy approach.
Whenever two numbers say $a,b$ have gcd equal to 1 .
Then Bezout's equation for them is
$ax+by=1$ for some values of $x,y$.
You said $a$ divides $bc$ .

So bc can be written as pa for some $p$........1

Now if you multiply $ax+by=1$ by $c$

You get 
$axc+bcy=c$

$axc+(bc)y=c$

$acx+pay=c$ from equation 1

Taking a common

$a(cx+py)=c$

Thus $a$ divides $c$ .

Comment: maybe you have lost an x from there $ax+by=1$ to there $ac+bcy=c$

Comment: Yes I am familiar with this proof, but how about the one I have, is it correct? I suppose there are many ways to prove this?

Comment: @Lukas  your proof is a right if you want to explain it to someone, but as an exam answer it would be lengthy approach.

Comment: @Lukas, your proof assumes the Unique Factorization Theorem. Are you allowed to do that? or is your result going to be used as part of the proof of unique factorization?

Comment: @Gerry I think on an exam I could assume that but Im not sure. It could be added to make it even more clear

Comment: @abhishek it is lengthy on purpose because I was told I needed to make it more detailed. Thats why I added a short version but maybe the short one is not sufficient in itself

Comment: @Lukas Then no problem ! Your proof is enough detailed to be understood.

Comment: Please ask your teacher, Lukas, whether or not you were meant to assume unique factorization. That's the only way we can settle this.

Comment: @gerry like I said above, I found an email from yesterday just now where he said I cant use FTA because this proof is meant to be a step to words proving FTA just like you said :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the idea right; I've always wondered myself why these sorts of statements are proved using algebraic manipulation when they are so much clearer when thought of in terms of prime factorization of numbers.

Perhaps your proof can benefit from a little more formality; for example, I would write the prime factorization of each number: $a=p_{a_1}^{i_1} \cdots p_{a_n}^{i_n}$, $b=p_{b_1}^{j_1} \cdots p_{b_m}^{j_m}$, $c=p_{c_1}^{k_1} \cdots p_{c_r}^{k_r}$ and use this notation to make the arguments in the proof.

Perhaps this is one drawback of the prime factorization approach; it can get very tedious very fast.

Comment: The problem is that what OP is trying to prove is usually given as a step along the way to proving the Unique Factorization Theorem. Using that theorem to solve OP's problem is then circular.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh I was not aware of that. If you do not assume this theorem, doe it get very difficult/long/impossible to profe FTA?

Comment: Most textbooks use it that way. It's not unavoidable, but it is the usual method. Anyway, I think the question here is whether OP is permitted to assume FTA.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe the OP is allowed to use FTA. He said that he rewrote this proof with the teacher's comments in mind. Thus it's likely that the teacher didn't object to the assumption of FTA.

Comment: I've had a few text that take the FTA as axiom.  I can see this as an exercise.  It's follows directly and rather easily from FTA but I think for a novice student it is a reasonably difficult but doable problem even with FTA.

Comment: FTA as an axiom? Sorry, I'll believe it when I see it. Which texts?

Comment: @Ovi, I haven't seen the teacher's comments – have you? Maybe the original proof had errors so severe that the teacher thought to deal with them first, and get to the more subtle points later.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Of course I can't be absolutely certain, but what seems likely to me is that the student wrote up a proof using this idea but with some mistakes, then tried to fix the mistakes and posted it here.

Comment: I can show you the original proof with comments if you like

Comment: I dont think my teacher would expert me to not assume fta but Imorgon not sure. Let med check my initial answer in exam

Comment: Actually I see now a recent comment from my teacher about this point your making. He says I cant use FTA which is what my proof is based on, because like you have said the profe is supposed to lead up to proof of fta

Comment: @gerry what your saying is exactly what my teacher is saying, i just didnt receive that email from him until yesterday and read it now. Thanks for clarification

Comment: And like you guessed it seems my teacher corrected what seemed a more servere mistake on the exam (which I didnt find satisfactory). But now I understand more

Comment: Even using FTA my original answers was not very detailed, maybe not clear enough, because I focused on a does not divide b but not so much on no factors of a divide b. So he gave the exemple of 6|12 but not 4 and 3 to prove that my argument was not correct.  But since I had also said "a and b have no common factors" i thought that should be enough in addition to a does not divide b. Anyway it is irrelevant because I cant use FTA

Comment: @Lukas If you want a user to recieve a notification of your comment you must type @ and then their *full* name.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Sorry I didnt know how to give you a notification. I have clarified your questions in commenta above

Comment: It's actually enough, Ovi, to use the first three letters of the name, but you have to obey the capitalization.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hmm interesting; I wonder what happens if there are two usernames in the thread with the same first three letters

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work, "Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John." Oh, and it appears I was wrong about the capitalization, as another part of that post says notification is case-insensitive.